# nginx x-accel-redirect with a etag comparison for 304 response

Tags: node.js, nginx, etag, x-accel-redirect

I am using a nodejs app behind nginx. This application serves protected images. I use nodejs to authenticate the users, and then issue an x-accel-redirect to an internal location to serve the image. This part is working fine.

Client requests route /auth/images/products/XYZ.jpg
Nodejs receives this request, checks authorization and then passes the x-accel-redirect header to the internal route /images/products/XYZ.jpg, which nginx then serves.

What is not working is that I would like nginx to issue a 304 response based on an etag comparison. All I ever get are 200 responses.

My nginx config is below. Please let me know what I might need to change to get the correct 304 response. Thanks in advance.

```
# set up upstream nodejs server
upstream nodejs {
    server 127.0.0.1:4000;
    keepalive 8;
}


# forward http to https
server {
   listen 80 default_server; # default handler for this port
    server_name domain.com; 
   #access_log  /home/nodejs/logs/nginx.log;
   #error_log /home/nodejs/logs/nginx_error.log;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}


# main server
server {
    listen 443 default_server; # default handler for this port  
    server_name domain.com;

    # security settings
    ssl on;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols           TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers             HIGH:!RC4:!3DES:!aDSS:!aNULL:!kPSK:!kSRP:!MD5:@STRENGTH:+SHA1:+kRSA;
    ssl_session_cache       shared:TLSSL:16m;
    ssl_session_timeout     10m;
    ssl_certificate /home/nodejs/project/ssl/dsa_bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/nodejs/project/ssl/dsa.key;
    ssl_stapling           on; # selfsigned=off
    ssl_stapling_verify    on; # selfsigned=off

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=63072000;
    add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

    resolver 8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8 valid=300s;
    resolver_timeout 10s;

    # other config
    charset UTF-8;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    # use sendfile when possible
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;

    # timeouts
    client_body_timeout 12;
    client_header_timeout 12;
    keepalive_timeout 5;
    send_timeout 10;

    #buffers
    client_body_buffer_size 100K;
    client_header_buffer_size 1k;
    client_max_body_size 10m;
    large_client_header_buffers 2 1k;

    #compression
    gzip on;
    gzip_vary               on;
    gzip_min_length         10240;
    gzip_buffers            10240 32k;
    gzip_comp_level         4;
    gzip_proxied            any;
    gzip_types          text/plain text/css text/x-component
                        text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml application/json
                        application/atom+xml
                        text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript
                        application/rtf application/msword
                        application/vnd.ms-powerpoint application/vnd.ms-excel
                        application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/vnd.wap.wml
                        application/x-font-ttf application/x-font-opentype;

    # logging
    access_log  /home/nodejs/logs/nginx.log;
    error_log /home/nodejs/logs/nginx_error.log;


    location ~ ^\/images\/products\/(.*)\.jpg$ {
        root /home/nodejs/project/private; 
        try_files $uri /images/products/Coming_Soon.jpg =404;
        #error_page 404 /images/products/Coming_Soon_sm.png;
        error_log /dev/null crit;

    access_log on;

    etag on;
    add_header Etag $upstream_http_etag;
    expires 24h;
        add_header Pragma "public";
        add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";

    internal;
    }



    # unprotected static content
    location ~ ^/(admin/assets/|admin/includes/|admin/js/|images/|fonts/|css/|img/|js/|lib/|views/) {
    root /home/nodejs/project/public;
        # error_page 404 /something_here??.png;
        access_log off;

    expires 24h;
        add_header Pragma "public";
        add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
      }

    # Set up node gateway for maintenance
    location / {
    # if maintenance page exists use that first
    root /home/nodejs/project/public;
    try_files /maintenance.html @proxy;

    access_log on;
   }

    # set up node proxy
    location @proxy { 
            proxy_pass http://nodejs; # can work with http internally. It's faster
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
             proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_connect_timeout       60s;
        proxy_send_timeout          60s;
        proxy_read_timeout          60s;
        send_timeout                60s;

        access_log on;

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your nodejs application needs to return the `Status: 304 Not Modified` header, then Nginx will return it for you.